# how to view details of a particular pod that has been exited using kubectl

Tags: kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I wish to view the logs of a particular pod (where I know the specific pod name from another logging application my company uses) using kubectl to determine the reason why it has continually been exiting with exitCode 143. However, when I run `kubectl get pods`, I am unable to see the specific pod I am looking for and only the pods that are running normally are listed. Would anyone know how I can get the details (and thus view the logs) for a specific pod name, even when it's no longer running?

EDIT: I have run `kubectl logs <podname>` but I cannot seem to find anything related to sigterm/exitCode 143 in the log output - is there another command I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this command

```
 kubectl logs <podname>  --previous
```

This will show you the logs of the last run of the pod before it crashed. It is a handy feature in case you want to figure out why the pod crashed in the first place

Within Kubernetes Explorer, the easiest way to get back to logs from former/previous pods may be to use the events tab. There you can see which pods shutdown with the timestamp along with a brief reason and message. Find the previous pod of interest, select it, then in the detail pane there is an option to view logs.

If u want to see details of deleted pod:

Get a list of recently deleted pod names - up to 1 hour in the past unless you changed the ttl for kubernetes events - by running:

```
kubectl get event -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name | cut -d "." -f1
```

You can then investigate further issues within your logging pipeline if you have one in place.

For exit code 143 refer to this [doc.](https://komodor.com/learn/exit-codes-in-containers-and-kubernetes-the-complete-guide/#:%7E:text=Exit%20Code%20143%20means%20that,will%20see%20Exit%20Code%20137)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot get the logs of terminated pods.